# How to set CLANG_ENABLE_MODULES = NO for pod generated project?

Tags: ios, objective-c, compilation, cocoapods

I'm trying to integrate [ccache](https://ccache.samba.org/) on my project which doesn't support clang modules. So I disabled clang modules in my main xcode project like below.

[image: CLANG_ENABLE_MODULES]

But for cocoapods generated project files, clang modules are enabled by default. Even if I change this setting, cocoapods will change it back on next `pod update`.

Is there anyway to let pod know that I want to fall back to the old behavior before apple introduced clang modules? Turn off CLANG_ENABLE_MODULES, **and link system frameworks used by other pod generated static library for me in my main project automatically, like AVFoundation, MapKit, etc**

Answer (score 0):

Are you a Chinese developer? Have you seen this article before?
https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/27584726

It's a tutorial of using `ccache` to speed up `Xcode` build process.It also provide the `config` of `cocoapods`.

I copied the code here, to let others who don't know Chinese and encounter the same problem know how to solve this problem.

```
post_install do |installer_representation|
  installer_representation.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      #关闭 Enable Modules (Translation:Close Enable Modules)
      config.build_settings['CLANG_ENABLE_MODULES'] = 'NO'

      # 在生成的 Pods 项目文件中加入 CC 参数，路径的值根据你自己的项目来修改(Translation: Add CC parameter to pods project. You can change the path to whatever you want.)
      config.build_settings['CC'] = '$(PODS_ROOT)/../ccache-clang' 
    end
  end
end
```

but this configuration only turn off `CLANG_ENABLE_MODULES`.
As far as I know, there is no way to link system frameworks when using `ccache` and `cocoapods`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, I'm from China as well. The article you referenced was written by me... I figured it out myself in the end, this is the correct answer.

Comment: What a coincidence! LOL! I just got benefit from your article. Thank you! 真巧！哈哈~ 我刚刚就是从你的文章收益了，感谢！

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a custom pod, in your podspec file, write something like this,

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|

    # some configuration

    s.pod_target_xcconfig = {
      'OTHER_LDFLAGS' => '-lObjC', # if you created a category for a class from other lib
      'CLANG_ALLOW_NON_MODULAR_INCLUDES_IN_FRAMEWORK_MODULES' => 'YES',
      'CLANG_ENABLE_MODULES' => 'NO',  # here is what you want
      'CLANG_WARN_DOCUMENTATION_COMMENTS' => 'NO',
      'GCC_C_LANGUAGE_STANDARD' => 'gnu17'
    }
end
```